# Enviar template e-mail HTML com PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, template

Pessoal estou tentando fazer o envio de e-mail usando phpmailer, mas com a mensagem utilizando template html, mas esta indo somente os codigos por e-mail, alguma dica de como fazer?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256464/7168666, se não me engano o css tem que ser inline, faz tempo que não mexo com disparo de e-mail...

Comment: Ajudou bastante, obrigada :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava esquecendo de colocar isto, então não estava reconhecendo o HTML.

```
    $mail->MsgHTML($template);
```